# if -OR statement with comparison operators not working as expected

Tags: string, powershell, if-statement, comparison

I have the following code snippet and I cannot figure out why the `if` is not working.

The goal is to get some input from the user, and if it is a valid input, carry on. If not, then keep asking until it is a valid entry.

No matter what value I enter on the first question (e.g. wmic), it ALWAYS goes into the `do loop`. When entering, say wmic, on the second pass, it breaks the do as desired. Invalid entries keep me in the loop until I enter a correct entry.

```
$query_means = read-host 'Enter one of psinfo, powershell or wmic'

if ($query_means -ne "wmic" -OR $query_means -ne "psinfo" -OR $query_means -ne "powershell")
{
do {
$query_means = read-host 'Invalid entry. Enter one of psinfo, powershell or wmic'

}Until ($query_means -eq "wmic" -OR $query_means -eq "psinfo" -OR $query_means -eq "powershell")

}
```

The `until` comparisons works just fine, breaking when desired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator. Let's say that `$query_means` is `wmic`. Then your first condition of `if` statement is `false`, however other two conditions are `true`. Since you are using `OR` operator, the result is `true`. Using `OR` operator you will always have at least 2 conditions that evaluate to `true`, so the overall result will always be `true`.

Instead you should be using `AND` operator, because you want condition to be valid when neither of the strings are in the list you provided.

So change `-OR` to `-AND` and your code should be fine:

```
if ($query_means -ne "wmic" -AND $query_means -ne "psinfo" -AND $query_means -ne "powershell")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and things work as needed now. To much in my OR frame of mind I guess.